# Print composer layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am new to QGIS and am trying to use the print composer.

My questions are:

1. How to change from vertical to horizontal orientation.
2. How to zoom in on a map that I've added.
3. How stop a black box from appearing every time I move my map.

Answer (score 3):

Ok first thing is first...you will get this a lot on this if you ask basic questions.....LOOK AT THE MANUAL. Look at the tutorial on youtube etc. etc.  But i do appriciate the panic when you cant figure basic elements..it goes after about a day of working.

1:  See the picture...i have take the liberty to address your potential next question (how do i change the paper size)
[image]

2:  Again see image.  Change scales. or using your mouse wheel and the move item content you can zoom in and out.
[image]
3:  As far as i can tell this is from processor speed and I, along with many other have asked/had/answered this problem a dozen times.  Note: not asprominat in 1.8 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

a) In QGIS 2.2, there's a Composition tab on the right side of the composer window, within the Paper and quality section, there is a dropdown in it for Orientation.
b) one way to do it is to reposition the layers in the main window, then in the right side of the composer window, in the Item properties tab, in the extents section, click Set to map canvas extent, and it will update according to the view in the main window
c) not sure--is it a large amount of data/rendering?